# How to hide db result if it has duplicate and the duplicate one have value specific value

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to get all products from database but hide these which are duplicate and have meta_value 'CX'.One product can have meta_value='NB','CX' or 'RN'.
If the meta_value is CX-hide, if its 'NB' or 'RN' -show them.But if the products is duplicated and the meta_value of one is NB and the other one is CX - not show.If NB and RN - show.
My code :

```
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM wp_frm_items WHERE user_id=%d ORDER BY created_at DESC", $user_id));
    //$array = array();

    if ($results) {
    foreach($results as $row) {

      $policy_transaction_type = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s", 390, $row->id));
      $policy_transaction_type = $policy_transaction_type[0]->meta_value;
      $policy_id = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT  meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s", 203, $row->id));
      $policy_start_date = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT  meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s", 170, $row->id));
      $policy_type_data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT  meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s", 200, $row->id));
      $policy_type = $policy_type_data[0]->meta_value;
      // $policy_id = $policy_id[0]->meta_value;
      $policy_wording = ($policy_type == 'Static Caravan / Park Home / Chalet')?'/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Static-Caravan-Wording.pdf':($policy_type == 'Touring Caravan'?'/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Tourer-Wording.pdf':'/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Lodge-and-Park-Home-Wording.pdf');
      $policy_summary = ($policy_type == 'Static Caravan / Park Home / Chalet')?'/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Static-Caravan-Policy-Summary.pdf':($policy_type == 'Touring Caravan'?'/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Tourer-Policy-Summary.pdf':'/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Lodge-and-Park-Home-Policy-Summary.pdf');
      $dateUK = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($policy_start_date[0]->meta_value));
      if(!empty($policy_id)){
        $array[] = $policy_id[0]->meta_value;
      }     

       //foreach ($array as $key) {
       if ($policy_transaction_type != 'CX') {
```

But now returns all the products.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems doesn't have correct approach. I suggest using exclude logic instead. Here is how to do it:

```
$excludes=array();
$results_exclude = $wpdb->get_results(
 "SELECT item_id FROM wp_frm_item_metas where meta_value LIKE '%CX%'"
);

foreach($results_exclude as $rex) {$excludes[]=$rex->item_id;}

$results = $wpdb->get_results(
$wpdb->prepare(
"SELECT id FROM wp_frm_items WHERE user_id=%d and id NOT IN (%s) 
 ORDER BY created_at DESC",
$user_id,implode(',',$excludes)));
```

That's all. $results will give you the ID-s which doesn't have any meta_value=CX row.

Comment: Yes, but if i have a duplicate :
Q-CID8120 - CX and Q-CID8120 - NB
It will show Q-CID8120.

Comment: no, it will not. because you exclude all id-s which has any relation with CX.

Comment: It returns this : 
Q-CID-14328097-NB-827
Q-CID-14328097-CX-825
Q-CID-14328097-CX-823
Q-CID-1507193624-NB-822
Q-CID-1510050174-RN-821<br>
Q-CID-1511814120-NB-820
It should return only :
Q-CID-1507193624-NB-822
Q-CID-1510050174-RN-821
Q-CID-1511814120-NB-820

Comment: it is because you wrongly described CX part in your question.  i have updated my answer, check it please. Now  meta_value='CX' is meta_value LIKE '%CX%'

Comment: The output now is : 
Q-CID-14328097-NB-827
Q-CID-1507193624-NB-822
Q-CID-1510050174-RN-821
Q-CID-1511814120-NB-820

Comment: It seems item_id has different value for each row? I thought item_id is the same for both Q-CID-14328097-NB-827 and Q-CID-14328097-CX-825 f.e.

Comment: yes they are with different item_ids.Any other ideas ?

Comment: What common field do they have? How you recognize that the product has two meta fields? What is the name of product ID field in your tables? I hope i can explain my point: there has to be a field which is common(same) for those fields.

Comment: Q-CID-14328097-NB-827 and Q-CID-14328097-CX-825 are meta_values and they are not the same. One ends with NB-827, another one ends with CX-825

Comment: Sorry..My table have four columns - id, meta_value, field_id and item_id
Q-CID-14-328097 is meta_value with item_id - 404
NB - is also meta_value with item_id - 404

Comment: yes, as you see item_id = 404 for both. i was right. So my exclude logic should work, if to implement it correctly

Comment: item_id is the same for one product but if its duplicated the item_id is different